# gfortran does not allow character arrays with varying component lengths

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

See the example below

```
 program test

 character(10),dimension(5):: models = (/"feddes.swp", "jarvis89.swp", "jarvis10.swp" ,   "pem.swp", "van.swp"/)

end
```

The following error is returned:

> Different CHARACTER lengths (10/12) in array constructor at (1)

There is  no error with ifort compiler. Why does it happen with gfortran and is there any way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: The error is about the right hand side. The characters in the array constructor have to have the same length, or the length have to be specified at the beginning of the constructor (available in F2003 only). The LHS is irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but do you have an idea why ifort compiler accepts with no errors the example I posted?

Comment: @MarcosAlex My reading of F2008 is that the compiler isn't required to diagnose the error in the code.  This could be just a helpful extension.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have some lengths 12 in the constructor, so it may be better to use length 12.

Also, use instead

```
character(len=12), dimension(5) :: models = [character(len=12) :: "feddes.swp", &
                "jarvis89.swp", "jarvis10.swp", "pem.swp", "van.swp"]
```

Possibly even better, if you have compiler support, is

```
character(len=*), dimension(*) :: ...
```

Comment: Good, I did not know this syntax for characters.

Comment: You guys showed, as Vladimir F suggested as well, how to specify the length at beginning of the constructor. I am wondering, though: why does ifort accept (no errors or warnings in  compilation) the example that I posted?

Comment: The compiler may be required to be able to detect the error in your code, but you may have a flag which allows it to be more relaxed.  Try `-warn all`.  That is, it could be accepting it as an extension unless you prohibit that.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but no warnings were shown. Also, when I executed printing the values of the vector, it performed well. It seems it has something out of the standard

Answer (score 3):

The original code is accepted by ifort but it is not standard fortran, hence the error from gfortran. If you supply the option `-std` to ifort it will print warnings when the compiler allows extensions such as this.