# Fortran Array of Strings

Tags: character-encoding, fortran

I am encountering a problem filling an array of character strings.
The problem occurs when using the [] declaration to assign elements
in an array. When I assign the array element my element, everything
is fine.

This is the output

```
Expected Output: redgreenyellowblue
Actual output: redgreyelblue
```

Here is the code

```
Character (len=*), Intent(in), Optional :: a2,     &
                           a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8  

Character (len=65), Allocatable :: str(:)
Character (len=65) :: b(512)

a1 = "red"
a2 = "green"
a3 = "yellow"
a4 = "blue"
a5 = "magenta"
a6 = "cyan"
a7 = "white"

Allocate (str(7))

str = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7]

str(4) = a4
str(5) = a5
str(6) = a6
str(7) = a7

Write (*,*) "Expected output: ", Trim(a1), Trim(a2), Trim(a3), Trim(a4)
Write (*,*) "Actual output: ", Trim(str(1)), Trim(str(2)), Trim(str(3)), Trim(str(4))
```

I have conformed that the following works as expected

```
Character (len=65), Allocatable :: str(:)
Character (len=65) :: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7

a1 = "red" ; a2 = "green"; a3 = "yellow"; a4 = "blue"
a5 = "magenta";  a6 = "cyan"; a7 ="white"

Allocate (str(7))
str = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7]
Write (*,*) Trim(a1), Trim(a2), Trim(a3), Trim(a4), Trim(a5)
Write (*,*) Trim(str(1)), Trim(str(2)), Trim(str(3)), Trim(str(4)), Trim(str(5))
Deallocate (str)
```

The solution is to include the character length parameter in the constructor

```
str = [Character(len=65) :: a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7]
```

Comment: First, what is the problem?  Do you get a compiler error?  If so, please report the error.  If you just get garbage output please state the output you get.  Second, I'm pretty sure the `[]` notation is not valid Fortran (unless it's in one of the newer standards)...

Comment: Did you mean something like `(/ a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7 /)`?

Comment: No compiler error. However when I output the array elements, they are truncated. When I assign each seperately, everything works fine. I am using gfortran 4.9, the [] declaration should work. For example it works with integers and reals.

Comment: Truncated how? Please update your question with your expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Have printed the output. Look at the first piece of code

Comment: Using `(/ /)` does not fix problem

Comment: In the array constructor all `a1`, `a2`, etc., must have the same length. These are assumed length dummy arguments, so can you show us the calling code?  And the declaration for `a1`.

Comment: FWIW, this person had the same problem: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/fortran-creating-array-containing-characters.418808/.  It looks like you have to assign each element individually.  It's probably because an array of "strings" is actually a multidimensional array which makes it difficult to assign the way you are trying to do.

Comment: With your new update, then it is clear that it is because you were using the `len=*` for the "a" variables, and the array constructor assumed that all the variables are the same length as the first element ("red", so 3).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21552430/3157076 regarding constructing from differing length variables.

Comment: I confirm @SethMMorton evaluation concerning the array constructor when using `len=*`

Comment: Link provided by @francescalus solves my problem. Need to compute the largest length of the character strings `a1, a2,...`.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the longest length of the `a`s: just use the length-65 of `str`.

Comment: The suggestion of @francescalus results in some cleaner code ar the computation for maximum length is avoided. In my case I like to keep character strings ured for printing to a maximum of 65 characters. 65 characters ir good recommendation for line readability.

Comment: gfortran 4.9 is not flagging the problem. NAG f95 fails with error.

Comment: The new code is `str = [character(len=65) :: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7]`

Comment: I have now also answered the question, ar I am sure it will be useful to others.

Comment: The output is now correct `redgreenyellowbluemagenta` is printed when using the variables `a` or `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include the character length parameter in the array constructor

```
str = [Character(len=65) :: a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7]
```

Comment: this is not correct Fortran.