# Fortran 90 Character array error

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have to calculate commissions for different interval of sales on different days and form a table "Day", "Sales", "Commissions". So far I've done this:

```
real::a(5),b(5)
character(10)::c(5)=(/Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday/)

open(1,file='in_1.txt')
open(2,file='out_1.txt')

read(1,*)(a(i),i=1,5)

do i=1,5
    if(0.<a(i).and.a(i)<99.)then
        b(i)=a(i)*.02
    elseif(100.<a(i).and.a(i)<299.)then
        b(i)=a(i)*.05
    elseif(300.<a(i).and.a(i)<499.)then
        b(i)=a(i)*.075
    else
        b(i)=500.*.1+(a(i)-500.)*.125
    endif
enddo

write(2,*)'   Day   ','   Sales   ','   Commissions   '

do i=1,5
    write(2,10)c(i),a(i),b(i)
    10 format(a10,t15,f4.1,t25,f8.2)
enddo

total=0.
do i=1,5
   total=total+b(i)
enddo

write(2,20)total
20 format('Total Commissions',t25,f8.2)

end
```

The sales from sunday to thursday are in the input file in_1.txt.

When run, it shows the error: Element in REAL(4) array constructor is INTEGER(4).

What does it mean and how to resolve it?

Comment: The compiler bulks at line 2. I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 as a compiler.

Comment: If this is your complete code then `implicit none` as your first line will show you why there is a problem

Comment: implicit rule -> Sunday = single-precision-real -> real(4) array -> Monday = integer -> Error ?

Comment: Indeed, @roygvib.  But I suspect the better answer is `Sunday` is not `"Sunday"`.  Mentioning that if character literals are meant, the array constructor isn't valid, for which a duplicate can be found.  So: I think clarification is required as to what the problem is.

Comment: @francescalus I also wonder if it is okay to have different lengths of character literals in the constructor (like ["a","bb","ccc"])? I remember that it can be illegal for some compilers... Unfortunately I have to go soon so I hope someone will help for this

Comment: @roygvib It isn't: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21552430.

Comment: @francescalus Exactly :D I also met with the same trouble before...

Comment: @francesclaus After using `implicit none` and `integer::i` as the first two lines, new errors appear: 1. Symbol 'thursday' has no IMPLICIT type. 2. Function 'c' has no IMPLICIT type.

Comment: So? This just points you towards the (second) comment of @francescalus. `thursday` is a variable, `"thursday"` is a character literal. The variable `thursday` has not been defined yet, that is what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using implicit typing which is masking your fundamental error.  Implicit typing assigns a type based upon the first character of a variable name.

The array initializer:

```
(/Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday/)
```

resolves the types of these undeclared variables as

(/real, integer, real, real, real/)

and emits an error because you have an integer in your array of reals.

You can see this more clearly with the test case below:

```
print *,(/1., 2, 3., 4., 5./)
end
```

This does not compile with the same error as yours:

```
arcon.f90:1:13:

 print *,(/1., 2, 3., 4., 5./)
             1
Error: Element in REAL(4) array constructor at (1) is INTEGER(4)
```

Thus, the types in your array constructor must all match and that is what the error means.

---

To fix that error would be to use all reals in your array constructor, but your actual issue is that you are using variables where you should be using string literals.  Change the line

```
character(10)::c(5)=(/Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday/)
```

to

```
character(10)::c(5)=(/"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"/)
```

but you'll find a new error:

```
 print *,(/"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"/)
                            1
Error: Different CHARACTER lengths (6/7) in array constructor at (1)
```

and to address that you want to change your initialization to

```
character(10)::c(5)=(/"Sunday   ","Monday   ","Tuesday  ","Wednesday","Thursday "/)
```

---

You should always use `implicit none` in your code to avoid masking your real error.  Your original array constructor with no implicit typing would have instead emitted the error

```
Error: Symbol ‘monday’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

letting you know that you either forgot to declare the variable `monday` or that it should have been something else, e.g. a string literal in this case.