# check if list/array of strings contains string

Tags: fortran

I would like to check if a given string is contained in a list/array of strings. In `python` I would do something like this:

```
test_string = 'alpha'

if test_string in ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']:
    print('found it')
else:
    print('it's not there')
```

A simple FORTRAN program mimicking this obviously doesn't work:

```
PROGRAM STRINGCHECK
  IMPLICIT NONE

  CHARACTER(len = 10) :: test_string
  CHARACTER(len = 10), DIMENSION(4) :: string_array

  test_string='alpha'
  string_array = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']

  IF (ANY( string_array == test_string)) THEN
     WRITE(*,*) 'found it'
  END IF

END PROGRAM
```

In fact, it already fails at the array assignment with

```
Error: Different CHARACTER lengths (5/4) in array constructor at (1)
```

Is there really no other way than to check every string explicitly?:

```
  IF ((test_string == 'alpha') .or. (test_string == 'beta') .or. &
      (test_string == 'gamma') .or. (test_string == 'delta')) THEN
     WRITE(*,*) 'found it'
  END IF
```

**UPDATE**

The commenters are indeed right, changing the construction of the array makes the string comparison work just as expected:

```
CHARACTER(len = 10) :: test_string
CHARACTER(len = 10), DIMENSION(4) :: string_array

test_string='alpha'
string_array(1) = 'alpha'
string_array(2) = 'beta'
string_array(2) = 'gamma'
string_array(2) = 'delta'

IF (ANY(string_array == test_string)) THEN
   WRITE(*,*) 'found it'
END IF
```

However, constructing the array in this way somewhat defeats the purpose of this undertaking, which would be to define the array of strings inside the `IF` statement, just like in my example python code.

**UPDATE #2**

Thanks to High Performance Mark, the answer to my problem was as easy as padding
all strings inside the array with whitespaces to make them the same length (**EDIT**: I replaced the `[...]` with `(/.../)` according to VladimirF's commend):

```
IF (ANY((/ 'alpha', 'beta ', 'gamma', 'delta'/) == 'beta')) THEN
   WRITE(*,*) 'found it'
END IF
```

This is distinctly different from `python`, where the whitespace would make the two strings differ.

Comment: Well, it seems your problem is constructing the array, not the check. Did you search for the error message? I am sure it was treated before on SO. Th if condition seems correct, do you have any indication it is not?

Comment: Worth noting, perhaps, that if the errors in constructing the string array are fixed then the logic of using `if(any(...` works just fine.  Yes, there is more than one error in the constructor for the string array.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark ok, sorry for spamming. I was actually hoping to specify the array of characters inside the `IF` statement, but reading the other questions I guess that is not going to be possible.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark you are right, my python code was 'not correct' in that sense -- fixed that now. Sorry for the confusion. Anyway, so if you understand you correctly, I just need to extend all my strings to 10 characters (presumably by padding them with whitespaces?) the comparison will work correctly? That would be quite surprising as whitespace has a value as well. I'll try it out.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Indeed it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, the Fortran standard explicitly states that when comparing strings of different lengths the shorter one is, effectively, padded with sufficient trailing blanks to bring it to the length of the longer one for the comparison.

Comment: Or use `[character(10) :: 'alpha', 'beta',...]`. It is in the link I just included in the duplicate list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552430/gfortran-does-not-allow-character-arrays-with-varying-component-lengths

Comment: @VladimirF yes I saw that, but as you mentioned there, this is only valid for F2003 onwards, but thank you anyway for mentioning it.

Comment: Which is widely supported nowadays. In C++ everybody uses C++14 or at least 11 so why not use 03 in Fortran? Even more, the `[` `]` parentheses are Fortran 2003 as well... You have to use `(/` and `/)` in Fortran 95.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm not sure if I can -- I'm fiddling with some pretty old code that has to compile on a range of different supercomputers and I can only test one of them.

Comment: Well as I said `[` and `]` is Fortran 2003 as well. The real supercomputers I have or had access to (ARCHER, IT4I) usually have the best compilers. Cray and Intel  Fortran 2008 compliant, gfortran almost.