# Compact if check involving multiple strings in Fortran

Tags: if-statement, fortran

Is there a way to check if a string is equal to any of the list together instead of individually explicitly check with a `==`? For example,

```
if(color=='violet' .or. color=='indigo' .or. color=='blue' .or.&
   color=='green' .or. color=='yellow' .or. color=='orange' .or. color=='red') then
   print *, "It is a rainbow color"
end if
```

Is there a way compact way to do this? Something like `if(color=='violet|indigo|blue|green|yellow|orange|red')` ?

Comment: This question is essentially the same as [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47828183/3157076) (but can't be marked a duplicate of it).  The essential premise is that you use an array, (constructing a character array [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21552430/3157076)), and use [`any`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8340592/3157076).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the colors into an array and use `any`.

```
if (any(color == [character(6) :: "violet","indigo","blue","green","yellow","orange","red"]))
```

Comment: I am sure my question has been answered already but the question you linked is different

Comment: @SKPS I did not actually link anything. This one is the same https://stackoverflow.com/q/47828183/3157076 but because it hasn't got an answer, it cannot be a duplicate target. Perhaps we can make it a target in the other direction now, even if the other one is much older.