# How to set up a small code easter egg in Fortran - randomly selected quotes for error messages

Tags: arrays, random, fortran, character

I've created a program which has a user interface to choose an option from a menu. This option is fed to an if statement which redirects it to the correct subroutine. I also have set up a small error message in case of option mistyping.

```
        else
        write(*,*)''
        write(*,*)''
        write(*,*)''
        write(*,*)'I am sorry, Dave. I am afraid I cannot do that!' 
        write(*,*)''
        write(*,*)''
        write(*,*)''
        write(*,*)' Press enter to return to main menu! '
        read(*,*)
        goto 300
    end if
```

And it all works fine. Thing is - HAL9000 has so many iconic phrases that would be so great as error messages that I would like to improve this `if block` with the possibility of providing the user with a randomly selected phrase from a set of pre-defined phrases. Examples of these phrases:

```
    'This mission is too important for me to allow you to jeopardize it.'
    'I know I've made some very poor decisions recently, but I can give you my complete assurance that my work will be back to normal.'
    'I've still got the greatest enthusiasm and confidence in the mission. And I want to help you.'
    'Just what do you think you're doing, Dave?'
    'Look Dave, I can see you're really upset about this.'
    'I honestly think you ought to sit down calmly, take a stress pill, and think things over.'
```

Well, at first I thought it was easy-peasy: just build a character array, pop the phrases inside of it, and then do something like this:

```
program pick_random
  implicit none
 
  integer :: i
  integer :: a(10) = (/ (i, i = 1, 10) /)
  real :: r
 
  call random_seed
  call random_number(r)
  write(*,*) a(int(r*size(a)) + 1)
end program
```

But apparently, that's not how Fortran seems to work, and a character array has apparently a [very different meaning](https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2018/01/25/character-arrays-vs-strings-in-fortran/) that I was hoping for!

Any suggestions on how to implement it?

Comment: Can you show your attempt with a character array?  It's precisely the thing I'd expect to use if I were doing this.

Comment: Perhaps the necessary concept, missing from the referenced article, is that one can define an array of character variables of specific length, such as `character(len=32), dimension(24) :: random_strings` .  Bob, as we say, is your mother's brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @HighPerformanceMark's remark and @francescalus' suggestions I managed to create the code - and it works nicely!

```
subroutine easter_eggs()
  implicit none      
  integer :: i
  real :: r
  character(len=100),dimension(8) :: easter_egg = [ character(len=100) :: &
    &"Are you from the future? Because I have not written such option yet! Wierd...!",&
    &"Mistakes allow thinking to happen!",&
    &"Let me state the obvious: Are you sure you type the keyword correctly?",&
    &"There are no easter eggs in this program. Yep! That is right! None! And you there is no such option!",&
    &"You have learned so much from your mistakes that you decided to make a few more, right?",&
    &"Just what do you think you are doing, Dave?",&
    &"I see you never do the same mistake twice - you like to do it often just to be sure!",&
    &"Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new! (Albert Einstein)"]
  
  call random_init(.false., .true.)
  call random_number(r)
  write(*,*) easter_egg(int(r*size(easter_egg))+1)
end subroutine easter_eggs
```

Comment: There is a [better form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552631/3157076) of the character array constructor which avoids having to do that painful padding with spaces.

Comment: Note, there may  be a problem with the above use of `call random_seed`.  The Fortran standard does not define whether this call will seed the PRNG with a new set of seeds or reseed the PRNG with a processor-dependent set of seeds.   Thus, `r` may always have same value.  It would be better to use `random_init`.

Comment: It has skipped me completely! Moreover, curious how the compiler didn't flag that!

Comment: With `random_init(.true.,..)` you are asking for a _repeatable_ stream. That means you get the same number each time.  Use `.false.` instead to get different (non-repeatable) numbers.